# Angularjs ngMap Conflict With Html image Map

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

I am using Ngmap in angular js , 
it works fine but there is requirement to have Image map in my html

**Html Image Map :**

```
    <img class="map" src="demo_usa.png" width="960" height="593" usemap="#usa" usemap="#usa">
    <map name="usa">
        <area href="#" title="HI" shape="poly" coords="225,521, 227,518, 229,517, 229,518, 227,521, 225,521" ng-click="StateSelect(1)">
    </map>
```

the above tag show image map but it also show google map , i used **ng-non-bindable** on map tag , it solved the issue  but it also disable ng-click="StateSelect(1)" on area tag .

**Angular Ng-map**

```
            <ng-map center="{{House.Latitude}},{{House.Lonitude}}">

                <shape name="circle" no-watcher="true"
                       stroke-color="#23b079"
                       stroke-opacity="0.8"
                       stroke-weight="2"
                       fill-color="#23b079"
                       fill-opacity="0.35"
                       center="{{House.Latitude}},{{House.Lonitude}}"
                       radius="300">
                </shape>

                @*<marker position="[{{House.Latitude}},{{House.Lonitude}}]"></marker>*@

            </ng-map>
```

Angular Ng-map work fine the problem is **html Image map** , it also show google map rather than html image map .

any solution ?

**thank you .**

Comment: [The reference documentation I found](https://ngmap.github.io/) indicates that you should likely be using the `ng-map` element and *not* the [`map` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map).

Comment: i am using ng-map for google map .

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that, but I don't actually see you using `ng-map` anywhere.  I see you using `map`, but *not* `ng-map`.

Comment: above <map name="usa"> is actually an html image map .and i dont intend to show google map with that.

Comment: So what is the actual problem here?  What you're showing us has nothing to do with ng-map directly.  I would encourage you to post the more code so that we can help with the context of your actual use case.  Without it, we're kind of lest grasping at straws.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem as you have got. You can terminate the map directive on your module config:

```
.directive('map', function(){
    return {
        priority: 99,
        terminal: true,
    };
})
```

Notices: by doing this, `<map>` will loss the ng-map capability and you have to use `<ng-map>` for google-map.